# How to disable warning messages arising after enabling source code fortification

Tags: c, compiler-errors

We have recently added the following compiler flags in our project as part of code hardening.

```
ARCH_CFLAGS+= -fstack-protector
ARCH_CFLAGS+= -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
```

For some builds, Werror is also enabled.

My problem is that after adding the above flags, we are getting compiler warnings for potential buffer overflows.

```
Ex. In function ‘memset’,
    inlined from ‘some_function’ at some_file.c:436:13:
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:84:3: error: call to __builtin___memset_chk will always overflow destination buffer [-Werror]
   return __builtin___memset_chk (__dest, __ch, __len, __bos0 (__dest));
```

This triggers a failure in the build process. We have to root cause the failure, patch it, re-trigger the build only to see it proceed a little further and fail at some other location.

Are there any means via which we can prevent these buffer overflow related warnings from showing up during compilation (without removing the hardening flags). In short, I want to avoid the `-Wstack-protector` flag behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just disable `Werror`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Disabling Werror will not be possible. a lot of effort was made in the past to resolve existing warnings. Werror was introduced to prevent further introduction of warnings.

Comment: We are trying to catch mem crashes during testing phase, but we need a stable build for doing this. Constant build failures due to these warning messages are proving to be a hurdle.

Comment: Warning/Error says "will always overflow destination buffer". If you do not correct this now, you will have much more trouble in your hands during testing phase. You are complaining about something that is good for you !

Comment: Does the code in some_file.c:436:13 in fact call memset() with a length argument that's too large?

Comment: @sanjit, why I asked was to try and make you stop and think if what you are asking makes any sense. You enable warnings and hardening and then want to sidestep it because it is too much work. Step back and think about if you as an organisation is ready for this, or then as others said temporarily disable `Werror`

Comment: Agree with your comments @ r_ahlskog